# How to form sql structure to get max total value

Tags: mysql

I have a table "sales"

```
transactionId  salepersonId amount
1                1          100
2                1          200
3                2          50
4                3          60
5                3          200
```

I like to find out how to get the salesperson with the highest total sale.
I know I need to use max and sum but I don't know how to combine them.
This is what I got

```
   select salespersonId, sum(amount) from sales group by salesperson;
```

This would give me the total sales of each person, but I am not sure the next step to get the  max.  can someone help me ?

Comment: what is it? mysql? or sql-server? on mysql, `order by sum(amount) desc limit 1`.

Comment: so, MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: Thank you everyone for answering.

Comment: Even if you did find an answer, please leave the relevant tags only on your question. Remember that the questions are meant to help other users too. I'm removing the SQL Server tag in this case, since you accepted an answer that uses code for MySQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select salespersonId, sum(amount) as total 
from sales group by salespersonID ORDER BY total DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

The standard SQL way is to use `order by` and `limit` or `top`

```
select salespersonid, sum(amount) as total
from sales
group by salespersonid
order by total desc
limit 1;
```

In SQL Server, you would use `top 1` instead of `limit 1`:

```
select top 1 salespersonid, sum(amount) as total
from sales
group by salespersonid
order by total desc;
```

Comment: you had an extra `LIMIT 1` on the SQL Server code, hope you don't mind that I edited it out

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
select salepersonId, sum(amount) from sales group by amount DESC limit 1
```

**OR**

```
select rec.id, max(rec.amt) from (select salepersonId id, sum(amount) amt from sales group by salepersonId) AS rec
```